# jquery Datepicker date range, wont shows years/months outside of it

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

Currently I have a datepicker that sets a range of dates using minDate and maxDate, however the date picker will only let me see the dates within those ranges. If for example the min/max was 2017-2018, it won't let me view 2019 dates or 2016 dates.
I have tried yearRange but this has no effect.

Comment: Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Please add date picker data